# How do I remove SPDY (mod-spdy)?

Tags: apache, debian, spdy

I have tested with SPDY how do I get the uninstall now?

`dpkg -r -P mod-spdy` or `dpkg -r -P mod-spdy-*.deb` does not work.

What am i doing wrong ?

I installed with:

```
cd /tmp
wget https://dl-ssl.google.com/dl/linux/direct/mod-spdy-beta_current_amd64.deb
dpkg -i mod-spdy-*.deb
apt-get -f install
cat /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mod-spdy.list
```

## Edit

`dpkg -r mod-spdy-beta` and `dpkg -P mod-spdy-beta` and it works: s

Comment: change to "SpdyEnabled off" in /etc/apache2/mods-available/spdy.conf